# SSL finding a file that is not there

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a wordpress site, and trying to get the ssl lock to show up.  But the issue comes with a file that I just cannot find.  It doesn't exist and I'm not sure where it is being referenced.

[error for file that does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klTBl.png)

Is there a way to block this file from being referenced at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the website is www.bulletcentral.com

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the reference and don't know what file it is on, you can use Windows Grep to run a quick search on all your theme files for Logo_Website.jpg.  Once you have found the file where that image is referenced you can edit it and delete the reference.

Google Windows Grep, it's free and comes in very handy